# Android keyboard. Disable keys

Tags: android, android-input-method

How can I "disable" (don't draw it pressed) keyboard's keys (but touching key) then I slide upon the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I am very new at Android development, but maybe I can help a little.

There probably is an event you can capture. Then you would have to evaluate the value inside the textbox and then remove that character from the textbox.

Look for an event that gets called when a key is pressed on the keyboard.